# Does an antiparticle leave a different (from the normal particle) mark in a bubble chamber experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, antimatter, quarks

Experimentalists usually have experiments where they scatter particles superheated transparent liquid, thus checking for the particle's traces.

These particles can be for example quarks, and antiquarks too.
What I do not find anything about, is whether the normal particle, like a quark would leave a different mark in the chamber then the antiparticle, like an antiquark? Or do they leave the same mark?

Question:

1. Do normal matter particles (like an upquark) leave a different mark in the bubble chamber in an experiment then their antimatter pair (like an antiupquark)?

After the comments, here is the correct question:

2. Why do normal matter particles have a trajectory in the bubble chamber that is bent in the opposite direction then the antimatter particle? What quantum characteristic makes them bend in different directions?

Comment: "Normal" and "anti" are arbitrary labels. For example, the proton and positron may be "normal" while the electron may be "anti". Or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Individual quarks cannot be seen in isolation in bubble chambers.

By placing a bubble chamber in a powerful magnetic field, charged particles can be distinguished from their antiparticles because their trajectories will be bent in opposite directions.

Comment: Can you please tell me why the trajectories will be bent in opposite direction? which quantum characteristic is responsible for that?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei Antiparticles have opposite electric charge.

Comment: @knzhou   what I mean is, would a neutron (composite, 0 EM charge) and an antineutron have trajectories bent in different directions?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei They would both go straight.

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei Have you considered just sitting down with a stack of good physics lecture notes and working through them? Judging from your questions, you certainly have the drive, mathematical background, and curiousity to learn them very quickly. Then you could answer most of the questions you've posted on this site and move on to deeper questions.

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei Aside from just going straight, neutrons are also invisible in a bubble chamber. Only charged particles show tracks at all.